# Errors using tabular

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent

T_{WS} (t) &= \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
$T_{WS} (t-1) + \sigma_{Zu}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O) * G_{Ges}(t) - \sigma_{Ab}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O) * W(t) \\
 -  \sigma_{Ver}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O)$ \end{tabular} \\



\end{document}
```

And I get 7 errors, although the PDF I get from TeXnic-Center exactly looks like the way I want it to look. What can I do to get a PDF that looks like the one I already got but without the errors.

Comment: You are missing a `\begin{align}...\end{align}` around the whole stuff. And I am not sure you can use a tabular environment in there at all (never tried it so far). What's the purpose of the `tabular` there?

Comment: You can use tabular but the it is not at all optimised for math use, and would be much better to use one of the AMS math alignments, which are needed anyway for the outer `T_{WS} (t) &= `

Comment: Basically I have the following code and the formular mentioned above is to large for on line
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{align*}
G_{Ges}(t) &= \sum \limits_{j \in J^{GV}} G^{GV}_j(t) \\
T_{WS}^{min} &\leq T_{WS} (t) \leq T_{WS}^{max} \\
T_{WS} (t) &= T_{WS} (t-1) + \sigma_{Zu}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O) * G_{Ges}(t) - \sigma_{Ab}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O) * W(t) \\ - \sigma_{Ver}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_{Mat}, O)  \\
\end{align*} 
\end{document}

Comment: don't add code to comments (the formatting doesn't work) update the example in the question to be a complete example

Comment: why are you using `\noindent` (it does nothing useful before an alignment)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code that compiles. I broke the long line  with the `aligned` environment. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` since `mathtools` does it for you, and you must not end an `align` environment with `\\`: this will add a spurious evrtical spacing. I took the liberty to convert  the indices which don't seem to correspond to a product of variables to `\mathrm`.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}

 \begin{document}

\begin{align*} G_\mathrm{Ges}(t) &= ∑ \limits_{j ∈ J^{GV}} G^{GV}_j(t) \\
  T_{WS}^{\min} &\leq T_{WS} (t) \leq T_{WS}^{\max} \\
  T_{WS} (t) & = \!\begin{aligned}[t] & T_{WS} (t-1) + σ_\mathrm{Zu}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_\mathrm{Mat}, O) * G_\mathrm{Ges}(t) \\
  & - σ_\mathrm{Ab}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_\mathrm{Mat}, O) * W(t)
  - σ_\mathrm{Ver}(T_{WS} (t-1), K_\mathrm{Mat}, O)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]